# Why do we subtract $1$ in this definition of the shannon entropy?

Tags: entropy, regularization, optimal-transport

In the context of entropic regularization, the (negative) entropy is involved in such way (last term):

[image]

Why do we subtract $-1$? So far, I have only known of the entropy being $\sum x_{i,j}\log(x_{i,j})$.

Whats the intuition or meaning behind it to do so?

Comment: Can you say where you found that formula? I only know the entropic regularization with the $-1$.

Comment: I mean I know the entropy to be defined without the $-1$. The question is what role the -1  plays in the entropic regularization.

Answer (score 0):

First note that subtracting $\sum_{i,j}x_{i,j}$ from the `usual' definition of entropy does not change the optimal $x$ in the optimization problem (this is since $\forall x\in \Pi(f,g)$ we have $\sum_{i,j}x_{i,j}=1$).

I would guess it is included so that things cancel when you write out the dual problem. Note the Lagrangian is (with the $1$ included in the entropy)

$$ L(x,\alpha,\beta)=\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j}w_{i,j}+\epsilon x_{i,j}(\log x_{i,j}-1)+\alpha^T(x\mathbb{I}-f)+\beta^T(x^T\mathbb{I}-g) $$

so that $ \partial_{x_{i,j}}L=w_{i,j}+\epsilon \log x_{i,j}+\alpha_i+\beta_j$, where a $-1$ has cancelled to simplify things.

In above $\mathbb{I}$ is the vector of all 1's.